# jquery: split and change color of element text 

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

my project in asp.net mvc.
 I have added SQL_Error property to my model. When all input value is rihth it is going to write it to DB. if there will some error when inserting to DB, it will return Error as ErrorMessage : WhatYouMustDo . and i am adding this error to modelState. and it will automatically showen in validation-summary-errors div generated by mvc.

it will shown as below : `<ul><li>ErrorMessage : WhatYouMustDo</li></ul>`

and now i want to change color of li text() after ':' char with jquery

`Result :`
`ErrorMessage:(color-->Red)`
`WhatYouMustDo:(color-->blue)`

i want best way to do it

Comment: can't you do this server side? Add css class or something?

Comment: no i can not. it is validation-summary-error div generated by mvc dynamically when there is some error.

Comment: can you give an example of this error? cause I think, `<ul><li>ErrorMessage : WhatYouMustDo</li></ul>` is wrong mark-up. Well, maybe.

Comment: yes of course. I have added SQL_Error property to my model. When all input value is rihth it is going to write it to DB. if there will some error when inserting to DB, it will return Error as  ErrorMessage : WhatYouMustDo . and i am adding this error to modelState.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Look at this [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qj8vc/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function()
              {

                  var str = $('li').text();
                  var substr = str.split(':');
                  var myhtml="<span style='color:red;'>"+substr[0]+"</span>:<span style='color:blue;'>"+substr[1]+"</span>";

                  $('li').html(myhtml);



              });
```

Comment: Yes correct . I assumed `:` once.If need we can can call it as a function and replace the text in the split by the function  parameter.But at that time also it should be one.

Comment: which is pretty much the same as the answer above?

Comment: yes thanks. it worked.and your given link is good to test jquery :-) i will use it.

Comment: Yes I first I saw the previous one and started coding.Then You edit you answer.I simply post what I did.After that only I saw your edits.