# JQuery change text in page by splitting paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress based site where for widgets have titles like

- Browse By Category
- Shopping Cart
- Newsletter
- Community Poll
- etc

Now, I want to display first word of each widget in blue colour and remaining words in black colour.
How do I do that?

(i.e. Browse, Shopping, Newsletter, Community in blue colour rest in black color)

I guess, we can do this using jQuery but I have no idea, how to do that.

EDIT:

Site: http://granitess.com/wp/

Comment: Use JavaScript's split() method to separate the words then apply the CSS to the first word in the array. Then use JavaScript's join() method to put them all back together. It's all out there on Google and not too hard to do.

Comment: i got some solution but when i try doing it, all occurrences are being replaced by first occurrence. I understand that, i need to use `each` method but i don't know where to pass that
I used following link to achieve above thing
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859647/jquery-split-and-change-color-of-element-text

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show us your code so that we can help to fix it?

Comment: I added link from which i got help and also the problem i am facing now in above comment, please check, thanks

Comment: You say "widgets have titles" and we need to see the markup for that. You need to show what you have tried or folks are not likely to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, get iterate all `.widget-title`, get its text, split by space and change first word with `<span style='color:blue;'>` and then join all words and set in `.widget-title` html. like

```
$('.widget-title').each(function(){
    var $title = $(this).text();
    var words = $title.split(' ');
    words[0] = "<span style='color:blue;'>"+words[0]+"</span>";
    $(this).html(words.join(' '));
});
```

**Edited:**

On your side your widget title is in `.widget h3` So try this -

```
$('.widget h3').each(function(){
    var $title = $(this).text();
    var words = $title.split(' ');
    words[0] = "<span style='color:blue;'>"+words[0]+"</span>";
    $(this).html(words[0] + ' <span style="color:black;">' + words.slice(1).join(' ') + '</span>');
});
```

or If you want same like as in your footer then you can try this

```
$('.widget h3').each(function(){
    var $title = $(this).text();
    var words = $title.split(' ');
    $(this).html(words[0] + ' <span style="color:#333333;">' + words.slice(1).join(' ') + '</span>');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer
I will test and let you know

Comment: Hello,
That is not working, Can you look at site http://granitess.com/wp and can you suggest me answer please

Answer (score 1):

My preferred solution would be to use the WordPress hook for widget titles.

```
function my_widget_title($title) {
    $parts = explode(" ", $title);
    $return = '<span class="first">' . array_shift($parts) . '</span>';
    if (sizeof($parts) > 0)
        $return .= implode(" ", $parts);
    return $return;
}

add_filter('widget_title', 'my_widget_title');
```

I haven't tested it, but theoretically this function sould split the widget title into it's words, add the `<span>` around the first word and return the new widget title, which you could then style with CSS.

You can add these lines to the `functions.php` of your theme, or even better, create a child theme for the theme you are using and add it there. That way it doesn't get overwritten when the theme gets updated.

Comment: Thanks for this, its a great code
But its not working for all widgets, its working only for some widgets.
my website is granitess.com/wp
You can see there,
Thanks again.

Comment: Well, as I said, I didn't test it. Without actually using it in your theme I can only guess. You can try playing with the priority, see the [WordPress reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter). Also, check what actually comes in via the `$title` parameter, maybe you have to account for html tags already in there.